# Differences between conan and conda package managers

Tags: conda, package-managers, conan

For `C/C++` packages, what are the practical differences, i.e. from the point of view of a developer, between [conan](http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/index.html) and [conda](https://conda.io/docs/index.html)?

Comment: I would say that despite they could seem somewhat similar at first sight, they are very, very different, so the "practical differences" side by side might not make much sense and be mainly opinion-based. Moreover, as a conan contributor I am too biased to respond to this question, so I would suggest to follow both tools "getting started" guides from their docs, trying to build a C/C++ application that will link with some packages retrieved from the tool.

Comment: From a (C++) [library](https://github.com/Dobiasd/FunctionalPlus/) maintainer point of view, for me the main difference (as of 2023) is that conda picks up new versions, which I release in GitHub, [automatically](https://github.com/conda-forge/functionalplus-feedstock/pull/15), while for Conan I need to open a [pull request](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/pull/19855/files) each time.